# ACF not showing after running loops

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In the below code, I call fields from Advanced Custom Fields plugin and only the first two show 'home_title' and 'home_content'. After these two I run two different loops to show the latest posts in a given category. After those loops run there are 4 more fields from ACF called. 'donate_title' , 'donate_content' , 'mission_title' , 'mission_content'. Which are not showing up (not pulling any content at all).

If I move these ACF before running the loops they all show up correctly. So I imagine there is a problem with these following the loops but cannot find the reason.

```
<div class="main-site">
<div class="home-title-1">
<?php the_field('home_title'); ?>
</div>
<div class="home-content-1">
<?php the_field('home_content'); ?>
</div>

<div class="home-boxes-cont">
<div class="box-left">
<?php
query_posts('cat=4&posts_per_page=1');
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="bl-img">
    </div>
    <div class="bl-title">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bl-content">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<div class="box-middle">
<?php
query_posts('cat=5&posts_per_page=1');
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="bm-img">
    </div>
    <div class="bm-title">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bm-content">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<div class="box-right">
    <div class="br-img">
    </div>
    <div class="br-title">
    <?php the_field('donate_title'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="br-content">
    <?php the_field('donate_content'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="mission-title">
    <?php the_field('mission_title'); ?>
</div>
<div class="mission-content">
    <?php the_field("mission_content"); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are any of those last four fields set on option pages?

Comment: They all have identical settings to the first two

Comment: Ok. Try storing them all in variables at the top of your code, and then echoing them out wherever you need them.

Comment: I tried adding it as a variable up top in: 
<?php
$dt = get_field('donate_title');
?>

Then 

<?php echo '$dt'; ?>

and am only getting the $dt to show

Comment: Echo $dt;  Not '$dt'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get custom field data from the original post after altering the global post data with your query_posts() calls, you need to reset your post data with the wp_reset_query() function. Place this function after each loop -

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

...

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Johnny, I was trying some of the other options but this was the easiest and got me what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are altering the global *wp_query* variable. When you do that and the the result is not `is_single()` then you cannot pull any ACF settings any longer.

Either reset the *wp_query* to its original setting for the page or store the vars in an array before you make any *wp_query* changes, and retrieve them as needed later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Scriptonomy, you should really just use [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).  This is exactly what this function is designed to do... custom loops outside the main loop.  You should rarely ever need to modify the global wp_query variable.

If you still want to use `the_permalink()` and `the_title()` without passing a post id, then scroll down the page to the section labeled "Access all post data" and you'll see how to use `setup_postdata()` to make it easier.